# How to change the style of an ImageButton programatically

Tags: android, styles, imagebutton

In this specific `Activity`, the user should select the destructor chosen of player 1 and player 2 in a rock paper scissors game.

I tried several approaches: the first one was to simply let the selected `ImageButton` clicked, but I do not found any solutions to achieve that.

The second was to set the choosen `ImageButton` unclickable and change its `Image`, like shown in the Image below. There, the "rock" was choosen for player 1 and nothing for player 2 yet. As you see, as soon I change the `Image`s of an `ImageButton`, the borders disappear.

[image]

I change the status of the `Button`s like this

```
public void onClickRock1(View v){
    choosenDestructor1 = 1;

    buttonRock1.setImageResource(R.drawable.rock_clicked);
    buttonRock1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_background_stay_clicked));
    buttonRock1.setClickable(false);

    buttonPaper1.setImageResource(R.drawable.paper);
    buttonPaper1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_background));
    buttonPaper1.setClickable(true);

    buttonScissors1.setImageResource(R.drawable.scissors);
    buttonScissors1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_background));
    buttonScissors1.setClickable(true);
    }
```

and for all other 5 `Button`s the same in analogy to this method. Now, I consider that overriding the style of the `ImageButton` with a simple `Image` make the borders of my custom `ImageButton` style disappear, but this is only guessing.

I wrote a second custom `ImageButton` style with different background color and same border, but I can't figure out how to set that style on the `ImageButton` from code.

So my question is, which method would be the smartest to solve this (I think is the third one, but maybe there's another one) and if it is the third one, how to set the style of an `ImageButton` from code.

**EDIT:**

In analogy to rgrocha's answer, I edited my `selector` (which was already integrated in the `custom_imagebutton.xml`) like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rock">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/button_background" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#FFF716" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rock_clicked">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/button_background_stay_clicked" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#FFF716" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rock">        
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/button_background" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>  
</selector>
```

and the `onClickRock1` method like this

```
public void onClickRock1(View v){
    choosenDestructor1 = 1;
    buttonRock1.setSelected(true);
    buttonPaper1.setSelected(false);
    buttonScissors1.setSelected(false);
}
```

Solving it like this had the consequence to make a `custom_imagebutton.xml` for each `ImageButton` (rock, paper, scissors), and following problems are here:
1. The border is not visible (which matters, because I would like to have these borders)
2. The `Image` isn't scaled anymore (which doesn't matter, because I like it more like this)

So basically, it looks like the image I posted above, except the `Image`s are a little bit bigger due to not scaling (in the `layout.xml`, I set `scaleType="fitCenter"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a drawable selector for each state you want to apply and set it as the main mage or the background, you choose the better fits your needs.

In this selector you can make the borders, colors, images, whatever you want change.

A selector looks like:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="@color/button_highlight" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    </shape>
    </item>
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="@color/menu_bg_selected" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html for the full drawables doc. For your case see "State Selector".

You can even change the state of the button programatically with setSelected(), setEnabled((), etc.

Comment: ok, this seems the easiest solution (as I already had a selector in the custom_imagebutton_style.xml). The only question remained is, how do I set the scaling? Before, I set the image from the layout.xml with `scaleType="fitCenter"`, but the image stays in foreground. So I set both the "standard image" and the "selected image" from the selector, but from there they are scaled differently. Plus, the borders are disappeared from new. Should I paste the selector in the original question for review?

Comment: What are the differences between the paper, rock and scissors images, apart of backgrond and border color? They looks like the same transparent images in both states. Iso your could put those images as the main image in the ImageButton view and use only one backgroup selector for all six buttons.

Comment: I don't think you should use a <shape> inside an <item> with a drawable attribute. Put the main image in the ImageButton src attribute

Comment: referring to the comment before, yes, that's obviously the best solution! thank you! (they were intended to be a little bit dufferent, but i like simplicity, and just changing the background seems nice to me)

Answer (score 0):

According to selectors, here is quick working example. I hope it will help you some.
Here works for buttons with specifed `android:background` source. This example shows how image is changing after clicking on it.

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClickButton1(View view) {

    //button is selected when false and vice versa
    view.setSelected(!view.isSelected());
    Log.d("xxx", view.isSelected() + "");
}

public void onClickButton2(View view) {

    //same here...
    view.setSelected(!view.isSelected());
    Log.d("xxx", view.isSelected() + "");
}

public void onClickButton3(View view) {

    //same here...
    view.setSelected(!view.isSelected());
    Log.d("xxx", view.isSelected() + "");
}
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:onClick="onClickButton1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:onClick="onClickButton2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:onClick="onClickButton3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

button_style.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/aselected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anone" />

</selector>
```

Images:
[image]
[image]

P.S To scale image you can use option:

```
<ImageView
android:scaleType="scaleXY" />
```